# Mongodb and Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-templates, mongoengine

I am currently working with two databases in my django app - mongodb for storing numeric data and mysql for handling relations and providing business domain background.

I have one concern:

First - I am using mongoengine along with django signals and custom tamplate tags. Meaning:

Whenever I call this filter. {{myobject|do_sth:"20"}} the process goes that way:

filter call -> myobject's do_sth property with argument "20" call -> send signal job_done -> receive signal job_done -> create monoengine document -> save it

I dont't know if that's clear but it's just a combination of different techniques - my problem is :
How is the efficiency problem in this case ? Has anyone tried that solution or has similar experience ?

Another question: Since, I relatively often use the process described above should I be concerned about number of items in mongodb collection. Let's suppose it will grow up to 10 000 in a week and than we clear the collection - is that fine ?

Comment: It depends on how long does the job_done process takes and how big the items in your mongoDB collection are (also called documents).

With mongoDB you can scale vertically (more servers) instead of horizontally (more ram, faster HD, etc)

You'll need to be more specific to get a better understanding of the problem

Comment: @GianPaJ you mixed up vertical and horizontal scaling

Comment: Yeah my bad. Horizontal is more servers.

Comment: Objects look like that: name, symbol,creation_date and ListField(up to 200 floats). They are stored in db for one week approximately. Actually the general process works pretty good, despite involving practically each application layer. The purpose of storing this numerical data is to keep track of the data users search for. Besides, it enables to generate complex reports for each name-list pair.

Comment: @user1642053 if you're using  mongo >= 2.2 then you can use [TTL](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) to automatically expire documents in a collection. Might be a bit faster than doing so manually.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that is too much logic for a simple template tag and it might be better to do in the view itself - at least thats what djangonauts would argue.

I take it you are outputting the results of the filter - rather than just calling the signals so data is created.  If you aren't outputting the results then make the processing offline and non-blocking for the user.  I've had great success with [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html) for long running / potentially blocking tasks (you dont have to complicate your stack as mongodb works great as the queue backend).

MongoDB in production with masses of data across large clusters - so 10,000 documents is a relatively tiny amount of data.

Comment: Agreed, I finally decided to get rid of filters, I am using model property to get the data I want and send the signal